# How can I add N more columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google

As of this writing, the default number of columns in Google Sheets is 29 columns.

I need more than 29 columns.

I would like to add N columns where N is something like 10 to 30 columns.

My request is similar to the "add N more rows bottom" button at the bottom of each Google Sheet GUI.

**Is there a way to add N columns via the default GUI? If yes, how?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Select a column where you want to add your N columns (left of there or right of there)
2. Shift-select the N number of columns that you want to add
3. Right-click
4. Click on "Insert N columns on left" or "Insert N columns on right"

[image: screen shot of context menu]

Answer (score 3):

To add N number of Columns > Right Click on the top left corner of the sheet so that it selects the entire spreadsheet > you will see the option to add 1000 Rows
and 26 Columns. 
I believe Google Sheets, by default shows only 26 columns to add and lets you add columns in multiples of 26 at a time.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I just figured out a nifty little way to do this. Even if you don't know JavaScript, this should be pretty easy to follow:

## Answer:

### Step 1 - Go to the script editor:

[image]

It will look like this:

[image]

### Step 2 - Name your file and replace the default text with this simple code:

```
function addColumns(x) {
    var columns = x;
    var columnArray = [];

    if(columns<11){
          columnArray.push("ERR: The minimum number of columns you can add is 11!");
    } else {
          columnArray.push(columns+" added! Delete Me Now!");
          columns = columns - 10;
          for (let i=1; i<=columns;i++){
                columnArray.push("");
            }
        }

return [columnArray];
}
```

Your script should now look like this:

[image]

### Step 3 - Save your script:

[image]

### Step 4 - Add columns by using your function in the rightmost column:

[image]

Note #1: Because of the way Google Sheets adds columns, there are a few constraints:

- You cannot add less than 11 columns.
- You cannot add columns beyond the 300th column (even if you call the function from the 300th column)

### Step 5 - Delete the contents of the cell and enjoy your sheet!

[image]

Comment: This is the one that worked for me! Great!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to insert or add more columns to my Google Sheets, so I downloaded the current one, edited it in Excel, and uploaded it back to my drive.

Answer (score 0):

In my search for the "add N columns" I did not find a GUI button and my Internet searches did not reveal such a feature. The "add N columns" may exist but I did not find it.

So I ended up using a workaround:

- add one column at a time via keyboard shortcut <kbd>alt-i</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>

As long as the number of columns you need is small, this workaround is sufficient, but if you have more than 100-1000 columns I would not recommend this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
If you need to add 11 columns, select 11 columns as shown in the screenshot 
[image: adding columns for Google spreadsheets]

Now. Click on Insert, here you can see an option to add 11 number of columns

[image: adding columns for Google spreadsheets]