# Add n columns to Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have seen [How to add N more columns?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/109809/how-to-add-n-more-columns) and I'm not satisfied with this solution.

Isn't there a way to specify how many columns to insert above/below a specified column? Why do I need to manually select that many columns to get that option?
How else to get an option to insert 20-30 columns without selecting that many.

Any way to make this a shortcut?

Comment: The question is unclear. Is it about rows or columns?

Comment: @Rubén both. I do not think it matters if it's the case of individual cells, rows _or_ columns. The pain area is that selecting n rows/columns is required to get the option to insert n rows/columns respectively. I find that bad and I want a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets doesn't include a "painless" built-in feature to insert several rows / columns at once but there are some alternatives

1. Use the macro recorder. You will have to do the "painful" procedure once but after that you could use a menu or custom keyboard shortcut to insert several rows at once.
2. Use the Google Apps Script editor to customize the recorded macro, i.e. to include a prompt asking for the number of columns / rows to insert and / or to create a custom menu
3. Use a Google Sheets add-on (if one exists) or create your own.

Comment: Hi, I like this solution but I am not so technically versed as to write the required code. How exactly do I begin writing my own macro script or building my own extension. A pointer in the direction, on how to begin, would be great. I'm very much open to learn. Thank you!